# Sample code changed to guard and pointing out the crash

Tags: ios, swift3, crash, uicollectionviewcell

Here is my code

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return self.getVideosArray.count
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    //let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "FullImageCell", for: indexPath) as! FullImageCollectionViewCell

     guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "FullImageCell", for: indexPath) as? FullImageCollectionViewCell else {
        fatalError()
    }

    let indexPath = indexPath.row
    //UserDefaults.standard.set(indexPath, forKey: "INDEX")
    //UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

    self.value = indexPath

    let videoStr = NSString.init(format: "http://52.2.212.171/wallpaper/admin/%@", self.getVideosArray.object(at: indexPath) as! String)
    self.downloadVideoLinkAndCreateAsset(videoStr as String)

    return cell
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    return CGSize(width: self.collectionView.frame.size.width, height: self.collectionView.frame.size.height)
}


func downloadVideoLinkAndCreateAsset(_ videoLink: String)
{
    self.bgView.isHidden = false
    // use guard to make sure you have a valid url
    guard let videoURL = URL(string: videoLink) else { return }

    let documentsDirectoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    // check if the file already exist at the destination folder if you don't want to download it twice
    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(videoURL.lastPathComponent).path) {

        // set up your download task
        URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: videoURL) { (location, response, error) -> Void in

            // use guard to unwrap your optional url
            guard let location = location else { return }

            // create a deatination url with the server response suggested file name
            let destinationURL = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(response?.suggestedFilename ?? videoURL.lastPathComponent)
            do {

                try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location, to: destinationURL)

                self.loadVideoWithVideoURL(destinationURL)
            }
            catch let error as NSError
            {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

        }.resume()
    }
    else
    {
        let getPathUrl = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(videoURL.lastPathComponent)

        self.loadVideoWithVideoURL(getPathUrl)
    }

}


func loadVideoWithVideoURL(_ videoURL: URL) {
    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: videoURL)
    let generator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
    let time = NSValue(time: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration)/2, asset.duration.timescale))
    generator.generateCGImagesAsynchronously(forTimes: [time]) { [weak self] _, image, _, _, _ in
        if let image = image, let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage(cgImage: image)) {
            let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
            let imageURL = urls[0].appendingPathComponent("image.jpg")
            try? data.write(to: imageURL, options: [.atomic])

            let image = imageURL.path
            let mov = videoURL.path
            let output = FilePaths.VidToLive.livePath
            let assetIdentifier = UUID().uuidString
            let _ = try? FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: output, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            do {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: output + "/IMG.JPG")
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: output + "/IMG.MOV")

            } catch {

            }
            JPEG(path: image).write(output + "/IMG.JPG",
                                    assetIdentifier: assetIdentifier)
            QuickTimeMov(path: mov).write(output + "/IMG.MOV",
                                          assetIdentifier: assetIdentifier)

            guard let targetSize = self?.collectionView.bounds.size else
            {
                fatalError()
                //return
            }

            PHLivePhoto.request(withResourceFileURLs: [ URL(fileURLWithPath: FilePaths.VidToLive.livePath + "/IMG.MOV"), URL(fileURLWithPath: FilePaths.VidToLive.livePath + "/IMG.JPG")],
                                placeholderImage: nil,
                                targetSize: targetSize,
                                contentMode: PHImageContentMode.aspectFit,
                                resultHandler: { (livePhoto, info) -> Void in

                                    guard let indexValue = self?.value else
                                    {
                                        fatalError()
                                        //return
                                    }

                                    let indexPath = IndexPath.init(row: indexValue, section: 0)
                                    print(indexPath)

                                    guard let cell = self?.collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath as IndexPath) as? FullImageCollectionViewCell
                                    else
                                    {
                                        fatalError()
                                        //return
                                    }
                                    cell.fullImage.livePhoto = livePhoto

                                    self?.bgView.isHidden = true
                                    //self?.livePhotoView.livePhoto = livePhoto

                                    //self?.collectionView.reloadData()
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Here I am setting live photo in the cell in loadVideoWithVideoUrl func. I changed to unwrap the value from ! to guard. And the app crashes at the end of func loadVideoWithVideoURL(_ videoURL: URL) where the I am setting the value to the cell.

```
guard let cell = self?.collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath as IndexPath) as? FullImageCollectionViewCell
                else
                 {
                     fatalError()
                      //return
                 }
```

Comment: What does the crash log says?

Comment: The log says: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: If the number of rows are 2 then the app does not crashes.

Comment: What is your array count?

Comment: It depends on the server side. But It will not exceed by 12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your crash is occurring because of the `!` in this line:

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "FullImageCell", for: indexPath) as! FullImageCollectionViewCell
```

Change it to:

```
guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "FullImageCell", for: indexPath) as? FullImageCollectionViewCell else {
  fatalError()

  return
}
```

If it crashes executing the `fatalError()` line, then the problem is that the cast of `cell` to `FullImageCollectionViewCell` is failing.

Comment: do I need to guard the cell in loadVideowithVideoURL func as well

Comment: If you don't know what line the crash is occurring, yes, I would use the `guard` method of unwrapping anywhere you're currently using a `!` to unwrap.

Comment: Yes, the app crashes from fatalError() statement.

Comment: Looking more closely at all of your code now, I see that there's more than those two places where you're using `!` to unwrap. Can you edit your question to show your sample code changed to `guard` and point out where exactly things are crashing?

Comment: I think the `indexPath` that you're passing in at the point of failure doesn't exist in the `collectionView` at that moment. Try printing the `indexPath` in the `else` block and setting a breakpoint there. When the breakpoint triggers, compare that number to your `dataSource`, which I think is `getVideosArray`, and see if it exists there. Moreover, I think it would be a better approach to alter your `dataSource` **first** and then `collectionView.reloadData()` when you would like to update your `collectionView`.

Comment: @AtplMohali would you mind Accepting my Answer as the answer to your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137321/discussion-between-atpl-mohali-and-daniel).

Comment: How to alter my datasource

Comment: @AtplMohali I messaged you in chat, but no reply. Let me know if you still need help.